# Default Android Studio compiler to offline, but also download things that's necessary

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am traveling in China for a few month and the network connectivity is weak due to the great fire wall. I have found enabling `Offline work` in Gradle setting super helpful. It reduced my compile time from a few minutes to a few seconds when I make a minor change in the `build.gradle` file.

However, I still need to manually turn it on and off if I introduce a new library to my project. So here comes my question:

Is there a way to default to `Offline work` and still download new library when needed?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following build command from android studio terminal.

```
gradlew --offline assembleDebug
```

Comment: Hi, this command doesn't work when a new library is added. `No cached version of org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1 available for offline mode.` for example. Of course I can simply not type `--offline` in that case, but I guess there isn't a way to handle this automatically.